# mod rewrite with a lot of parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to find a mod rewrite solution to my problem.

I have almost 6 parameters that i am passing to my url and i want to rewrite.

Let me demonstrate an example of 3 parameters (x,y,z)

The url is list.php?x=1&y=2&z=3 so a rule will be

```
RewriteRule ^list/x/([^/\.]+)/y/([^/\.]+)/z/([^/\.]+)/?$ list.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3
```

So far fine.

The really tricky part (at least for me) is that the parameters x,y,z have no predicted order so the url might be

```
list.php?z=2&x=4&y=9
```

OR

```
list.php?y=2&z=4&x=9
```

PLUS
the parameters can came not all together
EX

```
list.php?z=4
```

OR

```
list.php?x=7&z=7
```

OR whatever combination of 3 arguments

So for 3 arguments i have to write all possible combinations  (RewriteRule)

So my htaccess is actually 7 pages with 6 parameters and if want to add one more must write the new rules and correct all others

Is there any other way to accomplish it.

FOR EXAMPLE

if mod rewrite each parameter separate but when more than one parameter come from URL to combine the rules for each parameter.

EXAMPLE

```
RewriteRule parameter x rewrite to x/$1
RewriteRule parameter y rewrite to y/$2
```

So when both parameters come became x/$1/y/$2

OR some smart way that i dont have to write 7 pages of rules and be easier to modify

I hope its clear

Comment: If the parameters can be in any order, they shouldn't be passed as path info. Path info is only for hierarchical names.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use a query string?

Comment: Except that you're creating duplicate content, which is SEO unfriendly (http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359). Also, "list/x/1/y/2/z/3" isn't any cleaner than "list?x=1&y=2&z=3". What are the actual parameters you need to pass to the script?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
RewriteRule ^list/(?=(?:x/(\d+))?)(?=(?:y/(\d+))?) /list.php?x=$1&y=$2
```

Although it will produce empty parameters but that might be OK.

Comment: Thanks for your apply but i can not have empty parameters

Comment: So this would break? /list.php?x=&y=1